# Push Notification Suddenly Stops

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm new to iPhone app development.  I have the app with push notification, after it works for one and half days after the installation into my 4S (ios 5.0.1) for testing, it suddenly stops receiving alert message.  After some research, I have the APS/PC logging profiles loaded in my phone,  now I see the following log:

```
<APSCourier: 0xe60c910>: Connected to courier 1-courier.sandbox.push.apple.com. (17.172.238.205)

Jun  2 10:55:40 unknown apsd[60] <Warning>: <APSCourier: 0xe60c910>: Sending connect message with token '<2dd3393d 1d1e58ef 1692ba6b 64f6fa72 efb88099 c48375e5 ac9d6979 xxxxxxxx>'

Jun  2 10:55:41 unknown apsd[60] <Warning>: <APSCourier: 0xe60c910>: Stream error occurred for <APSTCPStream: 0x114b00>: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-9833 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -9833.)" UserInfo=0xe60e270 {}

Jun  2 10:55:41 unknown apsd[60] <Warning>: <APSCourier: 0xe60c910>: Disconnected in response to connection failure. (Consecutive failures: 14)

Jun  2 10:55:41 unknown apsd[60] <Warning>: Advising client to enter reconnect mode in response to a connection failure since currently in reconnect mode
```

I did rebuild app and re-installation into the phone, reissue new provision profile, reset network setting in iPhone, sent test token via airship with no error reported and even with request command to APNS directly from my own server without error, and turn off/on of notification center for the app in the phone, these actions do not seem to correct the problem.  Anyone has the idea how I can get this problem resolved?

Comment: I am getting the same error. The notifications suddenly didnt arrive anymore.

Comment: getting it too. Notifications get sent out but receive:<Warning>: <APSCourier: 0x146280>: Stream error occurred for <APSTCPStream: 0x1866a0>: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=54 "The operation couldn’-t -b-e -c-o-m-p-l-e-t-e-d-. -C-o-n-n-e-c-t-i-o-n -r-e-s-e-t -b-y -p-e-e-r-" -U-s-e-r-I-n-f-o-=-0-x-1-5-1-2-f-0 -{-}

Comment: I got an epic fail here. For me, it stopped working suddenly because there was not credit on my SIM Card left. From that point on, it didn´t work via the 3G Network. On Wifi, it never worked for me. I assume it´s because the port APNS is working on (5223) isn't open. Doing a scan with nmap showing only FTP, HTTP and Apple_Sync open.